# Read data from wordpress by external application

Tags: php, json, wordpress

I am quite new to wordpress and I am on my path to create my first plugin. I want to add a feature to my plugin, that I can read queried data from the wordpress db. I have already written a function to process the user data from wordpress, and echo them as json.

```
function process_data($type, $sdate, $edate)
{
    $data = array();

    global $wpdb;

    if($type == 'overview' || $type == 'users')
    {
        $data[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate))]['users'] = 0;

        $daily_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, DATE(user_registered) dte FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_registered>='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate))."' AND user_registered<='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate))."' GROUP BY dte");

        foreach($daily_users as $value)
        {
            $date = str_replace('-', '', $value->dte);
            $data[$date]['users'] = $value->cnt;
        }
    }

    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

However, how to read them with an external application. Any ideas how to call this function?

I would appreciate your answer!

Comment: If you want to enable open access from **any application**, I would suggest to work with [Custom Feeds](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds) instead. But be aware of what kind of data you are offering, this could turn into a huge security flaw.

Comment: @mathielo Thx for your answer! I will also add a key to identify at my application. However, I was wondering how to call this function and display the data in the browser? How to see the json object?

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you would want to create a [custom WordPress API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) if you would like to access this data from an external application.

Example:

```
add_action('rest_api_init', 'my_rest_routes_init_7464');

function my_rest_routes_init_7464() {
    register_rest_route('my-custom-endpoint/v1','/get-db-data', array(
                        'methods' => 'GET, POST',
                        'callback' => 'process_data'
    ));
}
```

Then you would need to change your function to:

```
function process_data(WP_REST_Request $request)
{
    if(isset($request))
    {
        if(isset($request['type']) && isset($request['sdate']) && isset($request['edate']))
        {
            $type = sanitize_text_field($request['type']);
            $sdate = sanitize_text_field($request['sdate']);
            $edate = sanitize_text_field($request['edate']);
            $data = array();

            global $wpdb;

            if($type == 'overview' || $type == 'users')
            {
                $data[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate))]['users'] = 0;

                $daily_users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, DATE(user_registered) dte FROM $wpdb->users WHERE user_registered>='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($sdate))."' AND user_registered<='".date('Y-m-d', strtotime($edate))."' GROUP BY dte");

                foreach($daily_users as $value)
                {
                    $date = str_replace('-', '', $value->dte);
                    $data[$date]['users'] = $value->cnt;
                }
            }

            echo json_encode($data);
            die();
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(array("error"=>"no request data"));
    }
}
```

The simply call your custom end point `http://yourdomain.com/my-custom-endpoint/v1/get-db-data/` from your external function using either GET or POST data for `type`, `sdate` and `edate`.

Caveat: You should consider creating a "secret token" that you can use to check requests and block requests that do not contain the secret token.